# POST axios request blocked by fluidpay api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to send a post request to this end point https://sandbox.fluidpay.com/api/token-auth and I'm getting this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sandbox.fluidpay.com/api/token-auth. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 405
```

When I send the request from Postman, it works. But when I try to send it using axios, I get the above error.

This is how I'm making the request using axios:

```
const request = await axios({method: "post", url: "https://sandbox.fluidpay.com/api/token-auth", data: {username: username, password: password}, withCredentials: false});
```

Shouldn't public API's be accessible to all domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

It looks CORS is disabled server side. If you don't control the server, you can't do much with a browser. The only way to solve the problem is using an API owned by yourself to proxy the request.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I posted the code incorrectly but I'm doing it the way you showed. After adding the `crossDomain` option, it still doesn't work.

Comment: what error it gives now?

Comment: It now says: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sandbox.fluidpay.com/api/token-auth. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 405`
By the way, I'm trying to get a JSON web token

Comment: Do you control che source code of the server hosted to sandbox.fluidpay.com? If so, you should include the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header in your server response. If you don't control the server, you can't do nothing. The only way to proceed is proxing the request from a server you control. So: browser -> your server -> fluidpay.com. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) you can read more about CORS

Comment: Thanks! Creating a proxy solved the problem. I used `createProxyMiddleware` from `http-proxy-middleware`.